# Merge 2 different languages into into single SOLR index using suffix - then how to query

Tags: php, solr, indexing, multiple-languages

I know that there are similar questions about solr and I read them all and some give insights but not a solution for exaclty what I am trying to do.

1. I have a table events that contains the columns eventid, name, description in English
2. I have a table esp_events that contains the columns eventID, name, description in Spanish

Right now we only index the english version so I want to add the Spanish version into the solr index also. As the eventid is identical in both tables I don't want to have that included for the indexing portion but obviously we will need it to pull the data from both tables using the same eventid.

So my questions are:

1. How do I define the data to be indexed (name, name_esp, description, description_esp).
2. Do I need to define a table that the data is sourced from - if so - how is that done.
3. How do I tell the php application to request the search be done against the English or Spanish version of the fields being searched upon.

I did not set up the original config for SOLR so I would appreciate you letting me know which files need to be modified to get this all to work. e.g. solr-config.xml and schema.xml - plus any I am not aware of.

I am also open to a completely different solution to the one I outlined - as long as its not too complex.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your existing schema.xml, version of Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually implemented by having separate versions of the field in the schema for each language, such as `name_en`, `name_es`, `description_en`, `description_es` etc. (as you write).

If you're using DIH, you can perform a join in the query (or use a nested entity) to retrieve the fields from the alternative language table as well.

If you know which language you're querying in, you can use `qf` (query fields) to tell Solr which fields to search. `name_es,description_es` if the search is in Spanish, `name_en,description_en` if it's in English.

There are also a feature in more recent versions of Solr (3.5 and up) for explicit [Language Detection](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing).

Comment: Fiskfisk, Thanks for the feedback. I did some research and I see if you use a text definition like test_es that solr will automatically treat the text as Spanish. Also, thanks for the qf hint to let solr know what language you are using - I do know the target language (en, es) based upon the source of the query (Spanish site or English site).